# database stopped on running 500 quires per second

Tags: ajax, database, jdbc, db2, livechat

I built a chat application in which chatting page is loaded per every 1second through AJAX,
And i used DB2 express-c database for storing messages.

one day 500 user at a time used this app at a that time database is stopped working.

Is their any effect on database by running 500 quires at a time in one second.

please tell how to run quires for every second without effecting the database functionality.

Comment: what do you mean with "database is stopped working", any error? log? anything you tried so far? 32 or 64 bit version of the DB2 express-c?

Comment: 64 bit version and it shown error on giving red mark on db2icon

Comment: yeah but what is the error message? how should one help you without any information? ^^

Answer (score 0):

The red mark on the DB2 icon means that the instance stop working. This issue should be related to a memory problem or something else.

You have to check the db2diag.log file, and check for message. It is highly probable that you have information at the time when the instance stopped. The first failrue data capture feature allows to recopile all that information when a crash occurs, in the diag directory.

In order to fix the problem, you just need to restart DB2. You can create a task that check if the instance is up, and if not, try to restarted. However, this is the wrong way to keep DB2 up.

You should see what happened at the time when DB2 crashed. Probably, the memory for the 500 agents was too high, and DB2 could not reserve more memory.

Are you running other processes in the same DB2 server? probably one of them corrupt the DB2 memory.